# Android Gradle sync failed - Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 5.4.1

Tags: android, gradle

After trying to import a module to my app I'm receiving an error :

```
Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 5.4.1.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle settings
```

Everything was working perfectly fine :/ Here are my Gradle files :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.60'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta02'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

And wrapper.properties file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

I tried to invalidate cache but it didn't work. Any idea ? Im going crazy!

Comment: Didnt work, tried that already

Answer (score 0):

You must going to new module folder and find `build.gradle` file and fix that file(change gradle version and other versions)

Comment: I have removed that module.

Comment: Look's like you didn't do it completely

Comment: Is it a way to check it ? I removed it in Android Studio , removed it from project folder ...

Comment: did you remove it from build.gradle (app module)